# R replace identical column character items with increasing number

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 60000 obs. of 4 variables in the following format:

[image]

I need to replace all character items in the first column with the same character with the number 1. So "101-startups" is 1, "10i10-aps" is 2, 10x is 3 and all 10x-fund-lp are 4 and so on. The same for the second column.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please read [how to make a reproducible example in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you need to do is  something like:

```
my_data$col_1 <- as.integer(factor(my_data$col1, levels = unique(my_data$col1))
my_data$col_2 <- as.integer(factor(my_data$col2, levels = unique(my_data$col2))
```

Probably a good idea to read up on `factors`

Comment: Made some edits - as the second column clearly isn't in alpha order already, need to make sure that `factor` doesn't reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

Try building a separate dataframe from the unique entries of that column, then use the row names (which will be consecutive integers).  If your dataframe is `df` and that first column is `v1`, something like

```
x = data.frame(v1 = unique(df$v1))
x$numbers = row.names(x)
```

Then you can do some kind of merge

```
final.df = merge(x, df, by = "v1")
```

and then using something like `dplyr` to select/drop/rearrange columns